# Change Twitter Widget appearance on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter

I have the following code in my document:

```
<a class="twitter-widget" href="url" data-widget-id="138843679974442730">Twitter Timeline</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

`data-widget-id` is connected to one style. Right now if there is a theme change on the website (I replace all responsible stylesheets and images) everything changes but the Twitter widget.

Since the widget itself is an iframe, I can't change any stylesheets attached to it.

Is there an easy way to change the style of the widget without reloading it (deleting the tag, creating the tag, running js)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight forward way of doing this, so I've decided to bring in another dependency that will be delaying the `onload` event..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

And here is the code that did the job:

```
var twitterBox = document.getElementsByClassName("twitterBox");
if (!twitterBox || twitterBox.length == 0) { return true; }
var twitterTimeline = document.createElement('a');
twitterTimeline.className = 'twitter-timeline';
twitterTimeline.href = 'url';
twitterTimeline.innerHTML = 'Twitter Timeline';
twitterTimeline.setAttribute('data-widget-id', '388742673974046720');
twitterBox[0].removeAttribute('data-twttr-id');
twitterBox[0].innerHTML = '';
twitterBox[0].appendChild(twitterTimeline);
twttr.widgets.load();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can style elements in the Twitter widget iframe using JavaScript.

First, you need the active document in the iframe's nested browsing context:

```
var doc = document.getElementById("twitter-widget-0").contentDocument;
```

Then, you can apply styles (e.g.):

```
doc.querySelector(".timeline-header").style["background-color"] = "black";
doc.querySelector(".timeline-header a").style["color"] = "white";
```

Example: http://codepen.io/smockle/pen/IJHnj

Comment: Unfortunately it throws SecurityError on this, as the stylesheet is from another domain.

Comment: @Xeos Which browser are you using? Does the widget on [this page](http://cdpn.io/IJHnj) display a black header?

Comment: MDN is warning about SecurityError as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet